# uiautomator Didn't find class " on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android-uiautomator

I have the problem when I add a java file to my project,the project struct is as below:

`ScreenLockTes.java` is the new java file and `DisplayTest.java` is the original one :

[image: ScreenLockTes.java is the new java file and DisplayTest.java is the original one]

Before I added the `ScreenLockTes.java` my project works fine ,but after I added that file and rebuild the project I got the problem.

my build and test step is :

```
1、android create uitest-project -t 2 -n screenlocktest -p 
E:\Users\ss\workspace\DisplayUIAutomationTestCses
2、ant clean build

3、adb push 

E:\Users\ss\workspace\DisplayUIAutomationTestCses/bin/screenlocktest.jar /data/local/tmp

4、adb shell uiautomator runtest screenlocktest.jar -c ScreenLockTest
when I use the above step 4 command to run the test I got the Didn't find class " on path: DexPathList error.
```

However,when I chang the command to `"adb shell uiautomator runtest screenlocktest.jar -c com.android.uiautomator.ScreenLockTest#SwipScreenLockTest"` the test can run correctly .And I find that eventhough the test can run.

It seems that the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` function attched to the  `SwipScreenLockTest()` function did not run at all.

What is wrong with my project?Do I have some wrong project configuration?

Comment: I think I have found out the reason,the name of every function must start with "test" ,or uiautomator cannot recognize it